# Hacking the GNOME 3 shells application Dock

Tags: themes, gnome-3, gnome-shell

I saw this cool photo for a gnome 3 theme as you can see the application "dock" displays somewhat differently then is norm.

This theme no longer appears this way, the dock is in its usual place.

So my question is how can I hack the shell to make the dock display like the photo (or anything else for that matter)? is it evan possible anymore?

I read one comment saying this was an old dock layout can the new dock be reverted?

Thanks

The image I was referring too
[image: http://i.imgur.com/MYFn2.jpg]

If you want to find the image just google something like: "tron gnome 3 theme" and look for the image with and odd (square with multiple columns of applications) application dock.

Comment: This is indeed an old dock layout. I don't think you can go back to it unless you install an old version. Also, I'd recommend asking on Super User, since this question is not programming-related.

Comment: By the way, it's called the Dash (the bit on the left), but this is an old draft of what became the Activities Overview. I don't know how difficult it would be to make it work with Gnome 3. (This was a `gnome-shell` draft that ran on Gnome 2, most likely.)